# The first two values of an array of lists become NULL when i expand the array

Tags: c, realloc

I have an array of lists that i want to double in size.I use realloc and when i start to populate the new array elements the starting elements start becoming NULL and i can't change their value.

```
int x;
Heads=realloc(Heads, TABLESIZE * sizeof(struct HTLink));
S=realloc(S, TABLESIZE * sizeof(HTHash));
for(x=TABLESIZE;x<TABLESIZE*2;x++)
{
    S[x]=(HTNode *)malloc(sizeof(HTNode));
    S[x]->Key=EmptyKey;
    S[x]->Next=NULL;
    Heads[x]=*S[x];
}
TABLESIZE*=2;
return S;
```

After i run this code the values of S[2] and upward are normal but S[0] and S[1] are NULL

Comment: Please upgrade to a [mcve].

Comment: If you only allocate `TABLESIZE` elements, then adressing anything beyond `x[TABLESIZE-1]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean `S=realloc(S, 2 * TABLESIZE * sizeof(HTHash));` instead?

Comment: Don't overlook the fact that the link addresses within the data become invalid if `realloc` repositions the memory block. If the linked items are actually in a contiguous array, you can use the array index values as links, instead of their addresses.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That solved it.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused on what the second argument of [`realloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/) is:

> `void* realloc (void* ptr, size_t size);`
>
> `size`: New size for the memory block, in bytes.

You are doing this:

```
S=realloc(S, TABLESIZE * sizeof(HTHash));
for(x = TABLESIZE; x < TABLESIZE * 2; x++)
```

which shows that you think that `realloc()` will expand the array's size by the second parameter. Change it to:

```
S=realloc(S, 2 * TABLESIZE * sizeof(HTHash));
```